# Understanding Secure Enclave (or equivalent) - Samsung S8+ SM-955F

Tags: security, pattern-lock, samsung-galaxy-s8+

I'm trying to understand the limits of the Secure Enclave (or equivalent, I'm not certain what its called) on the Samsung S8+

Specifically, does the secure enclave include any features related to time between attempts to access it?

I am asking as my partner has forgotten their pattern lock and is desperate to get certain data on her phone, and the timeout is now up to 30 minutes per guess.   I'm wondering if there are practical ways to bypass this timeout, or better yet brute-force or circumvent the password.  (Unfortunately her phone is registered to Google so "Find my Phone" works, but not Samsung, which appears to mean she can't reset the password without a factory reset)

Comment: Secure equivalent is iPhone term. It's Knox for Samsung. From "find my phone" you should have an option to reset your password. Not being registered with Samsung should actually make it easier IMO-though I haven't used Samsung phones for long

Comment: Also this https://android.stackexchange.com/q/197232/131553

Comment: @beeshyams - thank you for these comments - both useful (I had the misapprehension Knox was a "tamper fuse" which blew if you toggled your bootloader or somesuch.)

Comment: What you refer to is correct and a part of Knox. Were you able to reset pass word

Comment: @beeshyams thank you - no, as of yet my wife has had no luck guessing the passphrase, and I have found no alternative methods with merit (all the software that promises to do this that I have found are - when you ask them specifically - unable to do so!  I suspect they are all variants of the same tool)